Cartoon show about 5 dinosaurs with special abilities
I have seen this show in late 1980's early 1990's.
It is about 5 little cute dinosaurs (each from a complete different species of dinosaurs) and each one has a distinctive color. But they all have some sort of ability. I think one of them can punch holes into metal. Not sure what the others can do. there maybe someone who could produce stick tape. Another could produces soap bubbles. These abilities may sound weak and useless,but this is all they do to defeat their enemy.
They have a spaceship. They fight against a villain which has the letter Z as a logo/signature.
I remember one of the episodes, these dinosaurs were tricked by trusting someone/something which had the letter N as a log. It later turned out that this N was a Z rotated 90 degrees. 
The show intro and end credit has a very catchy song that I don't know how to describe since I am not a musician. Maybe I should suggest a feature in the META to be added to help in such cases.
The 5 dinosaurs include one that can fly (with a long beak) and a fat one (maybe shaped like a bear). In the intro song, these dinosaurs dance and rotate in a very cute way.
I think the show is European. Not sure, but the animation is very different from American shows.

You're looking for Diplodo (AKA Diplodos) from 1987.

The series Diplodo focuses on five dinosaur-like creatures, known as the diplodorians. These creatures are from Diplodorianrex, the sister planet of Earth, which lies in the fourth dimension. The story explains that whatever happens to one planet also affects the other planet. The Diplodos have successfully defended their home planet and put up a strong defensive shield. This results in the Diplidos' enemies, led by the evil Santos, targeting Earth in order to destroy the Diplodos' home planet.

Santos's logo is a Z and the 5 heroes have different colors and special abilities. Here's the intro, where the cute Diplodos all dance around and eventually fall over:




No sweat, your ID questions are exemplary. Even when they're about stuff I barely remember or don't even know, they contain enough details so I'll know I'm on the right track.

It could be DinoSquad

Five teenagers, Roger, Max, Caruso, Fiona and Buzz, gain the power to
  turn into dinosaurs by getting covered in ooze that mutated their DNA
  on a school field trip. With the help of their mysterious science
  teacher, Ms. Moynihan (who is an anthropomorphic velociraptor), they
  learn to use their unique abilities to protect the planet from Victor
  Veloci.


Here is the title sequence:




I have not seen DinoSquad. Looking at wikipedia, I am sure it is not DinoSquad.

There's actually an astounding amount of possibilities. There's also this and this...
